# Error estimates for inhomogeneous semidiscrete PDE

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I have the following semidiscrete problem on a meshed domain $U_h$. Let

- $V_h$ be linear finite elements on $U_h$, $V_{h0}\subset V_h$ have zero trace on $\partial \Omega_h$, and
- $V_{h\partial}$ be the trace of $V_h$ on $\partial \Omega_h$.

Given $\gamma_h: (0,T) \rightarrow V_{h\partial}$, I want to find $u_h: (0,T)\rightarrow V_h$ such that

$$(u_h',v_h)+(\nabla u_h,\nabla v_h) = 0$$

and $u_h = \gamma_h$ on $\partial \Omega_h$, for a.e. $t$ and all $v_h \in V_{h0}$.

I am interested in estimates of type $\|u_h\|_{H^{r,s}}\leq C\|\gamma_h\|_{H^{r',s'}}$. Are you aware of any source treating a such a case? I am interested in (close to) minimal regularity assumptions on $\gamma_h$. In particular, $\gamma_h$ interpolates some $\gamma$ defined on a smoother $\partial \Omega$.